# WSL causing my internet to not work

Tags: wireless, internet, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My WSL is causing my internet to not work. My Wi-Fi is shows connected but no traffic related to the internet is passed on.

When I restart my WSL by using the following command everything comes back to normal. Internet works fine after the restart but it vanishes again after some time so I have to use the following command again through the PowerShell:

```
Restart-Service LxssManager
```

Any help is highly appreciated. My gut feeling is that I need to install some drivers/tools on my WSL.

Note: I am on Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: Sounds like a Windows Problem, not a WSL problem.

Comment: When you have this issue, do you mean that your **Windows host system that WSL is running on** can't use the Internet?  That's usually a Windows issue not a WSL one.

Comment: @ThomasWard Thankyou for your comments. Let me clarify a thing. Everything works normal until I start Ubuntu from wsl. After a few minutes internet stops working until I restart my ubuntu by using Restart-Service LxssManager. So its not windows issue. If I dont start Ubuntu and just work normally in windows all is fine for hours and hours. I have tested it with a 12-15 hours work sprints.

Answer (score 0):

Check if  `/etc/resolv.conf` contains a line for a valid DNS nameserver.If not then remove any invalid entry and add the following line.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

*Your may add any other valid DNS nameserver instead of `8.8.8.8` which is Google's public DNS server*

Then restart resolvconf service

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

If it doesn't work try restarting your system

**If there is valid DNS nameserver then the problem might be due windows defender or any other antivirus firewall**